# YouTube Live does not work in Windows N without Media pack

Tags: windows-7, windows, firefox, video, youtube

I am running Windows N, and it seems that YouTube Live and the -N flavor don't play well together ([reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/46s3qa/h264_and_mse_h264_show_as_disabled_on_youtube/), [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/315wc8/h264mse_h264_are_both_red_on_youtube_windows_81_n/), [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/5c2fsu/help_youtube_live_streams_do_not_work_on_firefox/) (Doesn't apply to my PaleMoon) ).  Regular YouTube videos play fine, I only have a problem with livestreams.  It seems that Firefox (or Palemoon) requires Microsoft software to play HTML5 H.264 live streams.  The whole reason I chose Windows N was so I didn't have to have Windows Media player et al.  It seems that with Windows N, it's a de facto requirement to install the media pack ([Windows 7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16546), [Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48231)), which just installs all the software that was regulated by the EU to not be bundled with the OS, thereby defeating the point of Windows N.

How can I get YouTube Live working in Windows N without installing the media pack (thus defeating the point of Windows N)?

- Windows 7 Ultimate N 64 bit
- Firefox 55.03 (32 bit)
- Palemoon 27.4.1 (64 bit)

In searching Superuser, I found a [Q&A mentioning codecs](https://superuser.com/questions/665623/how-do-i-make-h-264-work-on-youtube-on-firefox-on-windows-7-64-bit?rq=1).  Installing the [K-Lite Codec pack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-Lite_Codec_Pack) had no effect, except to change my search settings and homepage to Bing(R) (d'oh!).

This is the symptom:

[image]

This is what YouTube thinks the problem is (highlights mine):

[image]

I came across [this extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-all-html5/) and tried to install it in Palemoon, but it won't install in Palemoon.

Comment: @qwerty - If answer to another question, answers this question, you should mark it as a duplicate.  **What you shouldn't do is vandalize another user's answer.** I went ahead and flagged this question as a duplicate. Due to the content of your last edit proposal I won't be accepting any of your proposals to my answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [H264 in Firefox on Windows 7 N without Media Feature Pack?](https://superuser.com/questions/813389/h264-in-firefox-on-windows-7-n-without-media-feature-pack)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I get YouTube Live working in Windows N without installing the
>   media pack (thus defeating the point of Windows N)?

What you want is not possible.  Firefox H.264 support depends on the operating system itself supporting it, which of course in the case of Windows 7, requires the installation of the Media Pack in order to add that functionality.

The requirement for the Media Pack, in order to support H.264, does not seem to extend to Google Chrome or Microsoft Edge.  Since you are using Windows 7 that basically means you are limited to Google Chrome, Opera, or Safari if you are attempting to avoid installing the Windows 7 Media Pack.

Comment: OK.  Well, at least now I know for certain.  It was starting to look like that, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: I run the N version of windows myself for the exact same reason as you, and ran into the exact same thing in the past with Opera and Vivaldi. I was not able to play youtube videos, or use soundcloud. In the end it all came down to missing the Media Feature Pack. Installed it, and all things that were broken regarding to media (video and audio) magically started to work again. Windows N is great, but only if you don't do much with video or audio playback.